# Use of spring boot to create single executable jar containing all direct and transitively dependent jar files

Tags: spring-boot

How to use spring boot maven plug in  to create an application which will have a single executable jar with all direct and transitively dependent jar files packaged into it and can be a standalone runnable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the spring-boot-starter-parent (or copy the spring-boot plugin config from there) and then "mvn package".

Comment: It created a jar file and in the lib folder it places all dependent jars but...How can i see the content of the jars...is this possible?i am using Java decompiler to see the content of those jars but nothing is being shown.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are getting at. The jars are there, so just open them up if you want to inspect them.

Comment: To look at the contents of a jar, simply unzip it